# Multiline regex captured twice?

Tags: regex, powershell

I can't find the correct regex to substitute the lines below (lines between **):

```
<variable name="RulesFile" property="RulesFile">CustomSettings.ini</variable>
</defaultVarList>
      </step>
      **<step>
      </step>
      <step>
      </step>
      <group>
      </group>
      <group>
      </group>
      <group>
      </group>
      <group>
      </group>
      <group>
      </group>**
    </group>
    <group name="Client Profile" description="">
```

I tried this :

```
$TS=[io.file]::ReadAllText("test.txt")
$TS -replace( "(?m)<step>\s+</step>(?:\s+<group>\s+<\/group>)*" , "AAAAAAA")
```

but the replacement string is inserted twice:

```
<variable name="RulesFile" property="RulesFile">CustomSettings.ini</variable>
</defaultVarList>
      </step>
      AAAAAAA
      AAAAAAA
    </group>
    <group name="Client Profile" description="">
```

How can I make the replacement to occur only once ?

Comment: Yes, twice, because you have 2 `<step></step>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match any number of `<step>` or `<group>` tag pairs that contain nothing but whitespace:

```
(?:<(step|group)>\s+</\1>\s+)+
```

You can generalize it further to match *any* empty tag pairs:

```
(?:<(\w+)>\s+</\1>\s+)+
```

Note the absence of the `(?m)` flag.  It only affects the start and end anchors (`^` and `$`), and you're not using those.  No special precautions are needed to match text that contains multiple lines.

Comment: Great, thanks for the generic regex! Clever use of `\1` which I never saw yet .Is it the very same as `$1` ? (I've edited your answer to espace the `/` )

Comment: Typically, backreferences inside the regex use a backslash (`\1`) while group references in the replacement string use a dollar sign (`$1`), but some flavors/tools use a backslash for both.  The *forward* slash has no special meaning in regexes.  You don't need to escape it unless you're using it as the regex delimiter, and Powershell doesn't use regex delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

There are two matches because there are two `<step></step>` entities, thus two replacements.

You could match everything between the first `<step>` and last `<\/step>` so that there is only a single match.

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/yW0lY1/1)

```
(?m)<step>[\s\S]+<\/step>(?:\s+<group>\s+<\/group>)*
```